# What is the difference between the CvCapture structure and the VideoCapture structure?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Is there any difference between the `CvCapture` structure and the `VideoCapture` structure in OpenCV? If so, when should I use `CvCapture` and when to use `VideoCapture`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`VideoCapture` is from the new C++ interface, `CvCapture` no longer has a public interface for use.

When using the C++ API, `VideoCapture` should be used.  You should avoid mixing the two interfaces.

If you are using the C API, rather than the C++ API, several methods return a `CvCapture` pointer, such as `cvCaptureFromFile`.