# Face detection to unlock door

Tags: c++, opencv

I found this code from opencv website and tried it out. I got this problem where detectAndDisplay shows an error saying incomplete type is not allowed, CascadeClassifier is not a type name, CvCapture is undefined and so on... How do I solve these errors

```
#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv\objdetect.hpp"
#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/** Function Headers */  
void detectAndDisplay ("Mat frame");

/** Global variables */  
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";  
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";  
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;   
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;   
string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";  
RNG rng(12345);   

/** @function main */  
int main( int argc, const char** argv )   
{
  CvCapture* capture;    
  Mat frame;    

  //-- 1. Load the cascades   
  if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };    
  if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };   

  //-- 2. Read the video stream    
  capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );    
  if( capture )    
  {    
    while( true )   
    {   
      frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );    

      //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame     
      if( !frame.empty() )    
      { detectAndDisplay( frame ); }   
      else     
      { printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!"); break; }    

      int c = waitKey(10);    
      if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; }    
      }    
  }    
  return 0;    
}    

/** @function detectAndDisplay */      
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )    
{    
  std::vector<Rect> faces;    
  Mat frame_gray;   

  cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );   
  equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );    

  //-- Detect faces    
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );    

  for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )    
  {
    Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );    
    ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );    

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );    
    std::vector<Rect> eyes;     

    //-- In each face, detect eyes    
    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );    

    for( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )    
     {
       Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );    
       int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );    
       circle( frame, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );    
     }   
  }   
  //-- Show what you got    
  imshow( window_name, frame );   
}
```

Comment: Where is `CascadeClassifier` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Windows?

If you are the first line should be #include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2//objdetect.hpp" I think (with double slashes before objdetect.hpp). This should be able to solve the problem with CascadeClassifier.

As for the CvCapture problem, which version of OpenCV are you using? I'm pretty sure it's no longer supported if you are using the latest versions (3.0 or above) and I'm not sure if it's still available in the older versions. See this [What is the difference between the CvCapture structure and the VideoCapture structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654623/what-is-the-difference-between-the-cvcapture-structure-and-the-videocapture-stru).

I'd suggest using VideoCapture instead http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture (looks like OpenCV 2.4 is not supporting CvCapture as well). They're pretty much the same thing and I'm using VideoCapture right now so it should work well!

Comment: Oh. I am currently using version 2.4.9 of opencv and the little mistakes has been cleared. I will try using VideoCapture and if if works, it would be great. Thanks!!!